# Drive-in movie speaker via Bluetooth and mini amp

Tags: amplifier, resistors, speakers

[image]

[image: speakerback]

I bought some drive-in movie speakers which I restored by cleaning up and replacing the old 4" drivers.The two drivers are 4" in size, 4 Ω and 5 W (dee pictures).

I bought a mini Bluetooth amplifier to hook up these two speakers so that I could play '50s tunes from my phone via Bluetooth cast out in mono.

It worked great for the short test runs I did but yesterday I lost all output from the mini amp (see picture of mini amp) which had an output of 50 W per speaker. I put both speakers onto just one output on the amp so it would be 10 W on that output leg.

The amp company through a very broken English email is telling me that the speakers are not large enough and it backed up the amp and overheated it. That may be true, but the amp was only on for less than 15 minutes and it was not hot when I went to see what was up with it.

The only advice from the amp company (they say they won't warrantee my purchase) is to buy another amp but hook bigger speakers up to it. I can't do that due to the nature of what I am trying to do with the drive-in speakers.

My question here is: Is there a way to put some kind of circuit/resistor in this mix somewhere that could fool the amp into thinking there are larger speakers and thus dissipating any output power that might otherwise back up and blow out the amp?

Please note with this request that I know NOTHING about wiring and circuitry so your answer would have to be very specific of what I should buy and where to place it in the mix (a drawing would be helpful). If any of you with a more technical side would wish to help me I would be so appreciative. I was supposed to show off this system at the end of the month at a drive-in which no longer uses real speakers. I was going to Bluetooth the radio broadcast of the movie onto my speakers.

[image]

[image: 4ohm5watt]

[image: miniamp]

[image: speakers]

Comment: What is the impedance (resistance) of the loudspeakers? We'd be more interested in looking at the back of them for any markings. Was the sound distorted? You can use a powerful amp to drive low-powered speakers but you have to control the volume level.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding. I will add a picture of the back of the speakers but I do not know the resistance other than they are 4 ohm, 5 watt (I am not a technical person just a guy who likes antiques). On the three test runs before the failure the unit ran for about 20  minutes a shot. The volume on my phone output as set high, the volume controls on the speakers was at full and i used the volume control on the amp for sound control. I was playing at a nice soft drive in movie type level if you know what that means and it was clear and perfect. Let me know what else I can provide - John

Comment: Re, "I bought some...speakers which I restored by...replacing the...speakers." There's another name you can use for the pair of items displayed on the funky blue blanket in your first photograph: When the whole assembly is a "speaker," you can call those items, "drivers," and you can call a  box that contains one or more of them a "cabinet."

Comment: thanks. I dont know all the terms

Comment: BTW here is an email excerpt from the amp manufacturer. "NS-20G amplifier is only suitable for 5-8 inches/4-8 ohms /20-120W speakers"  .......................... My drivers are 4' /4ohm /5Watt

Comment: That's a sweet job on cleaning up and polishing those enclosures. The pedestal and pole are fitting as well. Looks great!

Answer (score 1):

> The amp company through a very broken English email is telling me that the speakers are not large enough and it backed up the amp and overheated it.

That's baloney. As long as the speaker resistance is greater than or equal to the minimum load the amplifier can handle the amplifier will not be damaged. Typically those amplifiers can drive down to 4 Ω. If you confirmed that by measurement then that should be OK. The "40V" stamped on the rear is strange so I don't know what that means.

> That may be true but the amp was only on for less than 15 minutes and it was not hot when I went to see what was up with it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhkcbZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Connecting equal resistances in parallel halves the resistance. Connecting them in series doubles the resistance.*

That seems as though the load resistance is too low. If you connected the speakers in parallel on one channel then you have provided a load of only 2 Ω and this could be the problem. Instead you should have connected them in series.

The problem is further compounded by the speakers' own volume controls. We need a photo to debug that further.

---

Your new photo shows that the speaker volume control is a series-connected variable resistor. The problem now is that if we series connect both speakers the volume controls will interact. (One customer increasing the resistance on their speaker will increase the resistance on the series circuit, reduce the current and reduce the volume.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2wlkf.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A recommended wiring scheme.*

The wiring of Figure 2 solves a couple of problems.

- The circuits are independent.
- Adding the series 10 Ω resistor ensures that you never overload the amplifier and also reduces the risk of damaging the speakers if the amplifier volume is cranked up. Any value > 4 Ω will work here. You should choose a wire-wound resistor type with a power rating (watts) of several watts - 10 W would be safe enough and readily available.

One more thing: if your audio source is stereo and you only use one channel you will miss anything that is on the other side of the audio panorama. The solution to this is to bridge out the left and right channels of your 3.5 mm stereo lead. Ideally you would mix them with a few more 1/4 W resistors as shown in Figure 3.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhf7Jt.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. A simple resistor mixer to convert stereo to monaural (mono).*

Comment: Thank you for working on this. Those schematics were extremely helpful too and make it easy to understand how to get 8 ohms from the two speakers. As mentioned though the next issue are the volume controls on each speaker. I would of course like them to work but in the end if bypassing them and wiring the drivers  in series is my only option then I will have to live with that. I am just trying to keep the speakers as original as possible and was looking to see if each one could be boosted to 8 ohms independently. Above is a picture of the volume controls as found when I opened up the units.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: OK, I think I am getting it. Figure 2 is pretty clear but just to make sure:R2 and R4 are my existing volume controls and R1 and R3 are the new 10 ohm resistors? I can do that.

Comment: Correct. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: My real questions are related to figure 3. I am using the screw down terminals on back of the amp (one is R channel and one is L) and figure 2 looks as if I would just be using one side or the other. In trying to address the option of using both the left and right channels I have not been using the 3.5 mm aux input for anything yet, but is figure 3 a way to use that input to make the screw down terminal outputs on back (L + R) into mono? Im a little confused about what figure 3 is and how I would be connecting the speakers from figure 2 to it. My audio source will always be bluetooth

Comment: I forgot you were using Bluetooth (but you didn't write the trademark properly so I may have missed it!) so you can forget Figure 3 as it is only relevant if you were to use the headphone out from your phone into the 3.5 mm input jack on the amp. You can't connect the speaker terminals together or you will blow the amplifier output stage. Instead you should convert to mono on the Bluetooth transmitter. Android, for example [facilitates this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64047/stereo-to-mono-sound#:~:text=In%20S4%2C%20go%20to%20Settings,convert%20Stereo%20sound%20to%20Mono.).

Comment: ok. I just ordered two 10 ohm 10 watt wire wound resistors. They should be here by mid week next week and I will also have another mini amp by then. I am on a tight deadline because I am going to a drive in on the 26th. They do not have external speakers anymore so before the movies start I want to put this outside our car and play some 50s and 60s tunes on them. I could also conceivably use them to listen to the movie as the movie soundtrack is broadcast on radio and I can bluetooth it to the speakers. I will keep you all informed

Comment: Transistor, You have really saved the day here. Thanks for sticking with it. The bottom line here is never let a carpenter wire up sound systems!

Comment: OH! one more thing. Does it matter if the resistors (figure 2) go on the positive or negative lines?

Comment: No. In a series circuit the components can't tell the difference. It's the same current flowing through them all.

Comment: The tiny speakers you found will sound awful.

Comment: The power supply voltage sets the amplifier's maximum output power which is 10W into 8 ohms per channel when the power supply is 13V from a charged 12V car battery.

Comment: I wonder if the "40V" on the old drivers means that they were intended for use on a ["Constant-voltage" speaker system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-voltage_speaker_system).  70V would be more common, and there would probably need to be a transformer somewhere (inside the pedestal?) but that's the only place I've seen loudspeaker drivers with voltage ratings.  (The long distances involved in a drive-in would be a good reason to use this type of system.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using 2 speakers because they can feed mono audio to 2 cars.
The NoSound amplifier says minimum 4 ohms per channel but you connected two 4 ohm speakers in parallel to only one channel that overladed that channel with 2 ohms.
Why not connect each speaker to its own channel on the amplifier? Then each channel gets a 4 ohm speaker and works normally. Use the wiring in figure 3 to convert your phone's stereo into mono at the amplifier's input.

You never said the power supply voltage and current that you are using. The voltage and speaker impedance determines the output power into the speaker. NoSound says to use 19V at 4.7A then the amplifier will produce a max power at low distortion of 35W per channel into 4 ohms which will blow up your cheap little speakers when the volume is turned up higher than 5W. You can reduce the maximum output power by reducing the supply voltage but then the Bluetooth receiver might not work.

Reducing the volume with a variable resistor in series with a speaker makes a speaker sound boomy like a bongo drum. Drive-in and gas station speakers sound boomy.

If the amplifier chip is a REAL Texas Instruments chip and not a cheap Chinese copy then it is protected from damage when overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

> The amp company through a very broken English email is telling me that the speakers are not large enough

When that's the case, it's the **speakers** that overheat and get damaged, not the amp.

> and it backed up the amp and overheated it.

Nonsense. Audio amps are neither plumbing nor antenna drivers. They can't "back up".

*This is not legal advice and I'm not a lawyer!* If I personally bought it on Aliexpress or Amazon or even eBay, I would start a return of a faulty product. In case of Aliexpress, if they won't cooperate, then probably I would do a chargeback via the credit card company, but I could end up "banned" from the platform.

In any case, this thing failed through no fault of yours, as far as I can tell.